# How do I embed code through my text editor?

Tags: hugo

I'm running Hugo and editing my pages using Notepad++. I'd like to embed some code similar to the page here.

My Hugo version is

```
Hugo Static Site Generator v0.55.6-A5D4C82D windows/amd64 BuildDate: 2019-05-18T07:57:00Z
```

My config.toml file is below. As you can see, I've added the pygments options to the top of the page:

```
pygmentsCodefences = true
pygmentsStyle = "autumn"


baseurl = "https://blakeshurtz.netlify.com/"
title = "Blake Shurtz"
theme = "hugo-creative-portfolio-theme"
languageCode = "en-us"
# Enable comments by entering your Disqus shortname
disqusShortname = ""
# Enable Google Analytics by entering your tracking code
googleAnalytics = ""



[params]
  # Style options: default (pink), blue, green, pink, red, sea, violet
  # Use custom.css for your custom styling
  style = "default"
  description = "Describe your website"
  copyright = "&copy;2019 Blake Shurtz"
  sidebarAbout = [
    "I am a research statistician who enjoys building models and apps.",
    "Originally from the Bay Area, currently based in central CA."
  ]
  # Contact page
     # Since this template is static, the contact form uses www.formspree.io as a
     # proxy. The form makes a POST request to their servers to send the actual
     # email. Visitors can send up to a 1000 emails each month for free.
     #
     # What you need to do for the setup?
     #
     # - set your email address under 'email' below
     # - upload the generated site to your server
     # - send a dummy email yourself to confirm your account
     # - click the confirm link in the email from www.formspree.io
     # - you're done. Happy mailing!
  email = "you@yoursite.com"

    # Optional Matomo analytics (formerly piwik)
      # [params.analytics.matomo]
      #  URL = "https://stats.example.com"
      #  ID = "42"
      #  # Track all subdomains with "*.example.com" (Optional)
      #  domain = "www.example.com"
      #  # Optional integrity check hash
      #  hash = ""

  # Nav links in the side bar
  [[params.navlinks]]
  name = "Home"
  url = "portfolio/"
  home = true

  [[params.navlinks]]
  name = "About"
  url = "about/"

  [[params.navlinks]]
  name = "Get in touch"
  url = "contact/"

  [params.social]
    stackoverflow = "https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/206673/blake-shurtz"
  twitter       = "https://twitter.com/blakeobeans"
  email         = "blakeobeans@gmail.com"
  linkedin      = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/blakeshurtz/"

  github        = "https://github.com/blakeobeans"
```

Can someone give me an example of what I need to write in my text editor in order to include the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean using markdown syntax to format text as code.

Surround your code with three backticks at the beginning and at the end.

````
```python (or whatever language)
code here
```
````

Comment: You actually don't need to specify the language, unless it doesn't auto-detect it. Although I usually specify the language anyway

Comment: Some websites (like the one above, which I'm not promoting in any way), have automatic color editing. How is that done?

Answer (score 1):

As Ambrose Leung's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919037/11499871) mentions, you can include code blocks in markdown by wrapping them in 3 backticks:

````
```language
some code here
```
````

To get syntax highlighting, you can use Chroma, which is built into Hugo. Just add these lines to the top of your `config.toml` file (don't let the names confuse you, they say *pygments* but are for *chroma*):

```
pygmentsCodefences = true
pygmentsStyle = "pygments"
```

You can set the `pygmentsStyle` value to any of the styles from the [style gallery](https://xyproto.github.io/splash/docs/all.html).

Comment: Hi zwbetz, I added the two lines to the top of the configt.toml page to no avail. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: You could have other config options that are interfering. Edit your question to include the contents of your `config.toml` file, and your hugo version, then I'll take a look.

Comment: Hmm. Your config file looks fine. How are you writing your code snippets in your markdown files? Are you surrounding them with 3 backticks, and specifying the language?

Comment: BTW, just cloned your [theme](https://github.com/kishaningithub/hugo-creative-portfolio-theme), added those config lines to `exampleSite/config.toml`, added a markdown code block to `exampleSite/content/portfolio/work1.md`, then ran `cd exampleSite; hugo server --themesDir ../..`, and was able to see syntax highlighting at `http://localhost:1313/portfolio/work1/`

Comment: Hi, I was able to make it work by specifying the program language. Before I only had the backticks, now I have ```r